# min value of slider in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, xcode, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating an app using phonegap+jquery mobile.I have three radio buttons and a slider whose min and max values are set to 0 and 10 respectively. Now, if I would select some radio button and there would be a change event. I want to set the min value of slider to some other value such as 3 or 4 on this change event. 
I want to do this dynamically. I am able to change the 'value' parameter of slider, but how can i change the min value of slider?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the `min` attribute of the underlying `<input>` element and refresh the slider:

```
$("#yourSlider").attr("min", 4).slider("refresh");
```